# How to set map in Camel kafka option params

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

We have property called additional properties in camel kafka options which is of type map

```
 return "kafka:" + topic + "?brokers= " + host + "&groupId=" + group + "&securityProtocol=SASL_SSL"
                + "&saslJaasConfig=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required;"
                + "&saslMechanism=OAUTHBEARER"
                + "&sslTruststorePassword=changeit"
                + "&additionalProperties=AuthProvider"
                + "&sslTruststoreLocation=" + "truststore.jks"
```

Expected is map type & since we are building it with string uri then how can we pass map in above camel kafka option paramters.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Camel Kafka component documentation gives an example of how to configure `additionalProperties`:

https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/kafka-component.html#_endpoint_query_option_additionalProperties

You prefix each option with `additionalProperties.` followed by the name of the Kafka property you want to configure. For example.

```
from("kafka:myTopic?additionalProperties.transactional.id=12345&additionalProperties.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8811/avro")
```